# Fulltext match() against() returning empty set

Tags: mysql, index, full-text-search

I have a full text indexed table set up with the data Family in it.  There is no White Space and the spelling is correct.  How can I make this query match results as score and display them by score in DESC order? I keep getting empty set and don't know why.

```
SELECT *, MATCH(MEDIA_TITLE) AGAINST('Family') AS SCORE
FROM MEDIA_DATA_VIDS 
WHERE MATCH(MEDIA_TITLE) AGAINST('Family')
ORDER BY SCORE DESC ;
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution.  Thanks Anyways

See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-natural-language.html:

The search result is empty because the “search word” is present in at least 50% of the row entries, and so is effectively treated as a stopword.

my solution was to add more db entries so that the search term is less than 50% of the of the rows values.